# change javac (compiler) & java (runtime) versions in command line

Tags: java, path, version, command-prompt, javac

i have installed **JDK 7** on my windows 7 machine...

now in command prompt when i do

"**javac -version**" returns **1.7.0_25**

"**java -version**"  returns **1.7.0_25**

now my requirement is that 
i want to compile & run my java programs as **1.6**, without installing JDK 6 & without manually changing ENVIRONMENTAL VARIABLES PATH by going to MYCOMPUTER etc..

**i want to change compile time & runtime versions in the command prompt itself.**
HOW???

Comment: Change the `path` environment variable to point to the installation locations of the JDK and JRE

Comment: i want to change in the command prompt itself... and it is possible
i have done this 1 yr before...

Comment: Under `Windows`, `set path=\the\path\to\the\jdk\bin;the\path\to\the\jre\bin;%path%`

Comment: MadProgrammer... no no no... in command prompt, i just need to type... the version number and get it done... trust me it is possible... but i forgot..

Comment: Yes, changing the `path` environment variable at the command prompt will change it for FOR THAT SESSION, not the system as a whole...

Comment: Your other choice is to set up a series of symbolic links, allowing you to specify a single path and change the links as you need, personally, I think setting the `path` is simpler...but that's just me

Comment: yes i want for that session only... not permanent but how???

Comment: Just as I said.  Try it, see what happens ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Target different version of JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627606/target-different-version-of-jre)