# Target different version of JRE

Tags: java, compilation, version, javac

I'm testing Java on a Windows Surface Pro. The Surface Pro has Java 7 Update 55, but *does not* have the JDK installed.

I compiled a program on my MacBook from the command line using `javac`. The MacBook Has Java 8 Update 5 and it includes the JDK (obviously because I compiled on the MBP).

When I move the program from the MackBook to the Surface Pro, I get the following error. Here, "moving the program" means copying the two `*.class` files to the new machine and trying to execute the byte codes.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HttpsTest : Unsupported major.minor version 52.
```

Trying to compile with target information results in:

```
$ javac -target 1.7 HttpsTest.java SSLSocketFactoryEx.java
javac: target release 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8
```

`javac -help` does not list any options to control the version information of the compiled program (other than `target`, which does not appear to work).

How do I compile my source files for down level versions of a JRE? In this case, I'm targeting Java 7 from a Java 8 machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the command line, change your call to:

```
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 HttpsTest.java SSLSocketFactoryEx.java
```

The documentation for javac (for JDK 8) is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCBDCJI).

The documentation for javac (for JDK 9) is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9).

Note: In JDK 9, -target is replaced with --release.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `javac --release 7 Tmp.java` for javac with version 9 ~ 11, the available numbers for `--release` are `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse you can set compiler compliance level in the project properties-> Java Compiler. So your code is compiled for the chosen Java version. See here:

[image]

Comment: @sunleo I answered your question in a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

In the error message `major.minor version 52.` the number **52** here represents the java version with which the class is compiled
for example

```
Java SE 9 = 53
Java SE 8 = 52
Java SE 7 = 51
Java SE 6.0 = 50
Java SE 5.0 = 49
JDK 1.4 = 48
JDK 1.3 = 47
JDK 1.2 = 46
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

so  your installed JRE is at higher version than your target
use `-source` with the version number to which you want to compile 
in your case:

`javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 HttpsTest.java SSLSocketFactoryEx.java`