# Target release 1.6 conflicts with default source release 1.8

Tags: java

While generating jar file through command prompt getting "target release 1.6 conflicts with default source release 1.8".

Error screenshot

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627606/target-different-version-of-jre

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Target different version of JRE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627606/target-different-version-of-jre)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue.If you use wsc-23.jar file,then the issue is resolved as 
wsc-23.jar supports java 1.6,1.7 and 1.8 as well.
Check this for more information
[Target Release Issue](http://salesforceglobe4u.blogspot.in/2017/07/javac-target-release-16-conflicts-with.html)